# Java.NullPointerException null (again)

Tags: java, null, nullpointerexception

I am having another problem with NullPointerException. This time it is highlighting `tellen = telno.length()`. Beore you ask:

- There is data in the text file to be read to that variable.
- All variables were initialized.
- Buffered Reader is also initialized.
- Here is a snippet of my code:

  ```
  while((telno = br.readLine()) != null){
      name = br.readLine();

      surname = br.readLine();

      company = br.readLine();

      house = br.readLine();

      street = br.readLine();

      locality = br.readLine();

      postcode = br.readLine();

      telno = br.readLine();
      tellen = telno.length();

      mobno = br.readLine();

      sep = br.readLine();

      if(tellenx > tellen) tellen = tellenx;


  }
  ```

Please help. Thanks.
Text file:

- Name
- Surname
- Company
- House
- Street
- Locality
- Telephone number
- Mobile Number

Problem is in the telephone (tellen)
All these names are fictional, and this program is a telephone directory

```
George
Farrugia
Some Company 
9, Flowers
Quail Street
Bubaqra
BBQ 1569
21369854
79825643
--------------------------------------------
Paul
Zammit

9
Bird Street
St. Julians
STJ 0000
21545796
79745247
--------------------------------------------
Peter
Spiteri
Oak Company
Trees
Birch Street
Oakgrove
TRE 3333
21323323
99323323
--------------------------------------------
```

The blank after `Zammit` is a space. That is placed if there is no data to avoid a problem like this.

Comment: Why are you using readLine() repeatedly without null check?

Comment: Please post the stack trace for the null pointer exception. It probably has a clue to offer..

Comment: Can you post a sample of the input file.  You say that there is data for all fields it would be nice to see a sample.

Comment: You realize that you do `tellno = br.readLine()` twice, and ignore the first value right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is getting caused because you are reading `11` lines in one `while loop` instead you have to read `10` lines only.

So at some point `br.readLine()` will return `null`.

You need to read file according to your need that means in one go (your while loop) read 10 lines, then next 10 lines and so on.

```
while((telno = br.readLine()) != null){ // first line
    name = br.readLine();   // secondline I think this should be first line

    surname = br.readLine();

    company = br.readLine();

    house = br.readLine();

    street = br.readLine();

    locality = br.readLine();

    postcode = br.readLine();

    telno = br.readLine();
    tellen = telno.length();

    mobno = br.readLine();

    sep = br.readLine();  // eleventh line

    if(tellenx > tellen) tellen = tellenx;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me. With your answer I managed to solve this problem. Thanks again. When I'll have 15 rep points, I'll vote you up:)

Comment: You are welcome. Just a advice. Next time when you caught in this problem try to debug and find the problem yourself. It will help you in long run. If you are using Eclipse then [Eclipse Debugging Tutorials](http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm)

Comment: Actually, I am using BlueJ. To be frank, I am still studying for my 'O' Levels / GCSE Equivalent which is why I am not experienced in these matters.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably its the end of the file and  your `bufferedReader.readLine()` is returning **null** and you just invoked a method on an instance which is null, which leads to **NPE**.

Comment: There is data in the text file. None of the lines are null. It was working fine before I added another set of data. Same fields as this is what the program was designed to do.

Comment: @markscamilleri at the end of the file, if there is nothing to read br.readLine() returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to read using readLine() without null check.Definitel, it will give NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an if statement to check if there is any null references is a good practice to check for an error in your code.

An example in pseudo code would be:

```
   telno = br.readLine();

   if(telno == null)
       System.out.println("this will cause null pointer exception  "+ telno.length()); 
   else
       tellen = telno.length();
```

Comment: Tried it, and it is giving me a NullPointerException when there **IS** data. I don't know what's happening.

Comment: I think you mean to say `==` and you also need to remove lines after `if` and `else`.